# Cannot convert type 'WriteableBitmap' to 'LuminanceSource' on UWP for barcode decoding

Tags: c#, uwp, zxing

I'm trying to use ZXing on UWP project and I have read a lots of tutorials, that I can't get to work. The last tutorial said that I should use WritableBitmap, 'cos Bitmap is not awailable in UWP.

However it says to me

> Cannot convert type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap' to
>   'ZXing.LuminanceSource'

```
public class QrCodeHelpers
{
    public static void ReadQrCodeFromBitmap(WriteableBitmap image)
    {
        IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
        var generic = new BarcodeReaderGeneric<WriteableBitmap>();

        // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
        var result = reader.Decode((ZXing.LuminanceSource)image);
        // do something with the result
    }
}
```

How could I get this work? I have an image from MediaCapture and it would be fine to use that and get the QR code's data. Any solution?

Comment: You can't just cast like that if one object is not a subclass of the other.

Comment: Yep, I know it wont work, that's my problem. This is an accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650509/barcode-scanner-for-metro-apps  It uses the same...

Comment: @tixovoxi, The question you linked to has a link to codeplex example with media element. Nothing in that example has anything to do with LuminanceSource

Comment: Why are you casting in the first place? The "accepted answer" you mentioned just passes the bitmap reference without casting to anything. Please explain why you think you need to cast, and why you think that casting should work.

Comment: CTRL + DOT told me try to cast :D ...

Comment: @tixovoxi, anyway, have you checked my answer? Is that solve your problem?

Comment: i will tonight...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I agree with Peter Duniho.

Then, if you want to use `reader.Decode()` method, the parameter is actually [SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/c6967b87c2a806a799d5df96d75aa46faf88c727/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource.cs).

You can convert the `WriteableBitmap` to `SoftwareBitmap` at first and then convert it to `SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource`. And in your code `IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();`, is this a typo? `IBarcodeReader` is an interface.

Any way, you can code for example like this:

```
SoftwareBitmap sbmp = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(wbmp.PixelBuffer,
    BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
    wbmp.PixelWidth,
    wbmp.PixelHeight); //converter WriteableBitmap to SoftwareBitmap, wbmp represents the WriteableBitmap


//convert SoftwareBitmap to SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource
SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource luminanceSource = new SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(sbmp);

BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader(); //change IBarcodeReader to BarcodeReader
var generic = new BarcodeReaderGeneric<WriteableBitmap>(); //This code for what?
var result = reader.Decode(luminanceSource);
```